# Вырезать из текста программы комментарии

Tags: c++

Есть задачка, на входе дан текст (код программы с комментариями типа `/*коммент*/`). Нужно вырезать из этого текста комментарии и вернуть. Вот мой пример, но он не работает. Как его можно исправить ?:D

```
#define L 300

int main() {

    char s1[L]; // Входной текст 
    char s2[L]; // Выходной текст

    int fl = 0; 



    printf("Введите исходный текст (макс %d симв.): \n", L);
    gets(s1);
    printf("Начальный текст: \n");
    puts(s1);
    strcpy(s2,"");

    int i = 0;
    while(i<strlen(s1)) {


        if (s1[i] == '/' && s1[i+1] == '*') fl = 1;
        if (s1[i] == '*' && s1[i+1] == '/') fl = 0;

        if (fl == 0) {
            int j = 0;
            strcat(s2, &s1[j]);
            j++;
        } 
        i++;
    }

    printf("Выходной текст: \n");
    puts(s2);


    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: что должен сделать ваша программа? удалить `/**/` или добавить `/**/` ?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT вернуть заданный текст (текст /*строка*/ текст) без /*строка*/

Comment: А что будет если на вход придет что-то типа char a[] = "foo/*";/*real comment*/

Comment: а ещё нужно не допустить того, чтобы `int/**/x;` слилось в `intx;`.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов это допускается ))

Comment: @Accami допускается - одно, а годный результат - другое. Задача вырезания комментариев "несколько" сложнее, чем кажется ;-)

Comment: @VladD спасибо за int/**/x, завтра проверю наш софт под те же задачи.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Я на этом примере когда-то ошибся, так что это мои личные грабли. Удаление комментария должно на самом деле вставлять пробел на его место.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странный кусок, что вы хотели здесь сделать?

```
if (fl == 0) {
    int j = 0;
    strcat(s2, &s1[j]);
    j++;
}
```

P.S.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char CMT_START[] = "/*";
const char CMT_END[]   = "*/";

static char *remove_comments( const char *string )
{
    char *cmt;
    const char *sptr = string;
    char *copy = malloc( strlen( string ) + 1 );

    if( !copy ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    *copy = 0;

    while( cmt = strstr( sptr, CMT_START ) ) {
        strncat( copy, sptr, cmt - sptr );
        cmt = strstr( cmt + 1, CMT_END );

        if( cmt ) {
            sptr = cmt + sizeof( CMT_END ) - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Спорный момент: оставлять в строке незавершённый
             * комментарий или нет. В данном случае он будет
             * отброшен.
             */
            return copy;
        }
    }

    if( *sptr ) {
        strcat( copy, sptr );
    }

    return copy;
}

int main()
{
    char *s = remove_comments( "123 /* 456 */ 789 /* 098 */ abc /*" );
    if( s ) {
        printf( "%s\n", s );
    }
    free( s );
    return !s;
}
```

Comment: ну я думал сделать флаг открытия комментария и его закрытия. Тобишь просто записываем каждый элемент первого во второй, когда нашли коммент не записываем, а когда он закончился продолжаем, однако когда я вывожу strcat(s2, &s1[j]); текст выводится несколько раз, я не могу вдуплить почему ?

Comment: Для начала почитайте как работает функция `strcat()` и разберитесь что именно она делает, потом уже думайте - к месту и по назначению вы её применили или нет.

Comment: глупый вопрос, но почему в функцию strcat() отправляется указатель, а не копия переменной ?